# Vary number of objects in array

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my app the user can create unlimited UITextFields. then I get the information of all of them and upload in a json file:

```
NSString *object;   
NSString *object2;
 NSString *object3;
NSString *object4;
NSString *object5;
NSString *size;

for (UITextField *text in array2) {


int touchedtag = text.tag;

NSUInteger tagCount = touchedtag;
switch (tagCount) {
    case 1: 

        object = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", text.text, NSStringFromCGRect(text.frame), text.font];

        break;
    case 2: 
        object2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", text.text, NSStringFromCGRect(text.frame), text.font];

        break;
    case 3: 

        object3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", text.text, NSStringFromCGRect(text.frame), text.font];

        break;
    case 4: 

       object4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", text.text, NSStringFromCGRect(text.frame), text.font];

        break;

    case 5: 

        object5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@", text.text, NSStringFromCGRect(text.frame), text.font];

        break;

    default :

        break;

}
}
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"text", @"text2", @"text3", @"text4", @"text5", nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:object,object2,object3, object4, object5, nil];


NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSString* jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[jsonData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSString *destDir = @"/sandbox/";
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                withParentRev:nil fromPath:path];

[[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/sandbox/"];

}
```

The problem is that the number of objects is not independent (object, object2...). so if the user creates less than 5 text fields the app crashes, while if more than 5 nothing happens, but the info for tag 6 and on is not recorded. How can I vary the number of objects according to the number of fields created?

Comment: In answer to your question: Yes, there are ways  to vary the number of objects in the array. The first step is to read the spec for NSMutableArray.  Then you need to explain your problem well enough for us to understand where you're getting `object1, object2...` from.

Comment: You say that the user can create an unlimited number of text fields, yet your code can only deal with 5 objects. This is bad, you have to use a different design. As far as arrays are concerned, read the documentation for `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use NSMutableArray: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It allows you to add and remove objects "on the fly", just like using a `Vector` in many other languages. (Java, ActionScript, C++...)

**Example:**
(someValue is a previously declared variable)

```
stuff = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: someValue];
[stuff insertObject:object1 atIndex:0];
[stuff insertObject:object2 atIndex:1];
[stuff insertObject:object2 atIndex:2];
```

...

This code is to initialize it with a specific number of objects, which seeems to be what you are looking for. NSMutableArray also allows you to adjust the number of objects in the array at a later time.

Comment: no, I don't want a specific number, I want a number that depends on the number of fields

Comment: If you have the number of fields in a variable, you can use that for `initWithCapacity`.